# Fmincon in matlab running out of memory

Tags: memory, matlab

I am using Matlab's fmincon to optimize an objective function which is the l2 norm between 2 vectors. There is also an inequality constraint which is another l2 norm between the vector to be optimized and some other constance vector. So basically the number of parameters is the size of this vector which I am trying to minimize in an l2 sense.

|| M*s - s ||_2 s.t. ||s-t||_2 < epsilon

M is a constant matrix, t is a constant vectors and epsilon is a constant.

So now the problem for me is that s is huge. It can have from anywhere 400 to 20000 variables. Now fmincon runs out of memory when internally trying to store matrices. Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run fmincon, you should consider adding a set of options. look at [optimset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/optimset.html),
so do :

```
OPTI = optimset('MaxIter',1000)
```

or checkout all the [optimization options](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/f19175.html).

then

```
get_val = fmincon(... , OPTI)
```

if that doesn't work you should post your code

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't really solve my problem. I ended up realizing that I need to pass a user supplied "sparse" hessian matrix (earlier I was using the default setting for hessian which is approximation by finite differences). And once I did that I stopped running out my memory. But thanks anyways !